# How to custom color of Folder Name?

Tags: 20.04

I have lots of folders whose names illustrating the characteristics of their contents. Finding the target one is very time-consuming because their names share a similar format.

How can I make the folder name display in different colors according to its format? E.g.
a folder named "[user]*{date}*(notes)" display the text in [] with red, text in {} with green, the text in () with yellow, others with black.

Nautilus may not support this feature, but if any file manager (graphical- or terminal- based) can do this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: You do not mention the file manager you use (Files, aka nautilus, i.e. the default file manager of the Ubuntu desktop?). Anyway, I know of no file manager that supports such feature, neither graphical nor terminal based.

Comment: Probably not even `ls` supports this. It can use colors but only on the whole name.